Calculate Difference between two dates without including weekends(Saturday and Sunday) in PL?SQL
I need to calculate Daysin_process between two dates such that Saturday and Sunday are not included .Also it should consider start date and end date in calculation.
for example 1 -
start_date = 26-07-2024 and 
end_date = 29-07-2024 

so Daysin_process will be 2 as it excludes saturday and sunday.
example 2 -
if start_date = 28-07-2024 (sat) and end_date = 29-07-2024(mon) 

Daysin_process = 2 excludes sunday
I have a logic to calculate Saturday Sunday -->
FUNCTION is_weekend (p_date IN DATE)
  RETURN BOOLEAN
IS
BEGIN
  IF TO_CHAR (TRIM (TO_CHAR (p_date, 'DAY'))) IN ('SATURDAY', 'SUNDAY')
  THEN
     RETURN TRUE;
  ELSE
     RETURN FALSE;
  END IF;
END;

Write a pl/sql query for this logic also , i might another condition which will exclude holidays!
Please help guys!!
start Date  End Date        Expected Days
07/26          Fri  07/29   Mon 2
07/26        Fri    07/30   Tue 3
07/24          Wed  07/26   Fri 3
07/28        Sat    07/29   Mon 2 


This question is similar to: Get only business days in oracle sql. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
